# Require a textbox to have value in FIllable PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe, pdf-generation

I have a fillable PDF file. I would like to require that a TextBox has a value when the user saves the PDF document i.e. the value is not blank.

Here is what I tried:

**(1) Setting the "Required" field on the "TextBox".**

*PROBLEM: That didn't do much except color the textbox red.*

**(2) I tried to use the following code in the "onBlur" event:**

```
f = getField(event.target.name)
if (f.value.length == 0)
{    
   f.setFocus()    
   //Optional Message - Comment out the next line to remove
   app.alert("This field is required. Please enter a value.")
}
```

*PROBLEM: If the user never clicks this box there is no problem*

**(3) I tried to use the "Validation" tab and run a custom JavaScript.**

*PROBLEM: If you don't click on the box there is no validation so it is perfectly happy to leave the textbox blank if the user forgets to fill it in*

OK, I am out of ideas... Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Acrobat JavaScript I assume you use a viewer that supports and executes Acrobat JavaScript.
 In this situation you can set the document's WillSave action to a custom JavaScript action and perform validation here. I'm not sure if you can cancel the save operation but at least you can display an alert if the validation fails.
**UPDATE**: This script will loop through all the fields and display and alert if the field value is empty.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++) {
    var fieldName = this.getNthFieldName(i);
    var field = this.getField(fieldName);
    if (field.value.length == 0)
    {    
        field.setFocus()    
        app.alert("Field " + fieldName + " is required. Please enter a value.")
    }
}
```

Put the script in document's Will Save action and it will run every time the user saves the form. In Acrobat you set this in Tools > JavaScript > Set Document Actions and select Document Will Save.

Comment: How do I do that? Sample code? I'm a newbie when it comes to JavaScript so I piecing this together using google search.

Comment: I do not have much experience with Acrobat JavaScript but I'll try to help you with a code sample.

Comment: yes, but where do I put this script? What is the function I can use that will be called before a "Save" happens?

Comment: The Document Will Save action is called automatically by Adobe acrobat before saving the file. You just put this script as the body of the action.

Comment: See the end of my answer about how to use Acrobat to do this.If you're using another tool let me know.